Error deploying adls Linked Service artifact using az synapse module
Aim: Deploy linked service with below configuration using az synapse or powershell

Issue: Though the deployment works, the final linked service gets created with null service principal key which is failing the connection.


Check Event Viewer on Server and see if there are any error messages?  Also check the response status which should be 200 OK if successful or a 400/500 error status.
